# How term frequency is calculated in TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I searched a lot for understanding this but I am not able to. I understand that by default TfidfVectorizer will apply `l2` normalization on term frequency. [This](http://blog.christianperone.com/2011/10/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-ii/) article explain the equation of it. I am using TfidfVectorizer on my text written in Gujarati language. Following is details of output about it:

My two documents are:

```
ખુબ વખાણ કરે છે

ખુબ વધારે છે
```

The code I am using is:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize_words, sublinear_tf=True, use_idf=True, smooth_idf=False)
```

Here, `tokenize_words` is my function for tokenizing words.
The list of TF-IDF of my data is:

```
[[ 0.6088451   0.35959372  0.35959372  0.6088451   0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.45329466  0.45329466  0.          0.76749457]]
```

The list of features:

```
['કરે', 'ખુબ', 'છે.', 'વખાણ', 'વધારે']
```

The value of idf:

```
{'વખાણ': 1.6931471805599454, 'છે.': 1.0, 'કરે': 1.6931471805599454, 'વધારે': 1.6931471805599454, 'ખુબ': 1.0}
```

Please explain me in this example what shall be the term frequency of each term in my both documents.

Comment: You can refer to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting

Comment: I refered that also. Can't get the value after normalization.

Comment: post your original data here for which you have shown the TF-IDF... it has 2 documents.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for the prompt response. I have updated my question by adding two documents text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Now lets go through the [documentation I gave in comments](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting) step by step:

Documents:

```
`ખુબ વખાણ કરે છે
 ખુબ વધારે છે`
```

1. Get all unique terms (`features`):  `['કરે', 'ખુબ', 'છે.', 'વખાણ', 'વધારે']`
2. Calculate frequency of each term in documents:-

   a. Each term present in document1 `[ખુબ વખાણ કરે છે]` is present once, and વધારે is not present.`

   b. So the term frequency vector (sorted according to features): `[1 1 1 1 0]`

   c. Applying steps a and b on document2, we get `[0 1 1 0 1]`

   d. So our final term-frequency vector is `[[1 1 1 1 0], [0 1 1 0 1]]`

   **Note**: This is the term frequency you want
3. Now find IDF (This is based on features, not on document basis):

   `idf(term) = log(number of documents/number of documents with this term) + 1`

   1 is added to the idf value to prevent zero divisions. It is governed by `"smooth_idf"` parameter which is True by default.

   ```
   idf('કરે') = log(2/1)+1 = 0.69314.. + 1 = 1.69314..

   idf('ખુબ') = log(2/2)+1 = 0 + 1 = 1

   idf('છે.') = log(2/2)+1 = 0 + 1 = 1

   idf('વખાણ') = log(2/1)+1 = 0.69314.. + 1 = 1.69314..

   idf('વધારે') = log(2/1)+1 = 0.69314.. + 1 = 1.69314..
   ```

   **Note**: This corresponds to the data you showed in question.
4. Now calculate TF-IDF (This again is calculated document-wise, calculated according to sorting of features):

   a. For document1:

   ```
    For 'કરે', tf-idf = tf(કરે) x idf(કરે) = 1 x 1.69314 = 1.69314

    For 'ખુબ', tf-idf = tf(કરે) x idf(કરે) = 1 x 1 = 1

    For 'છે.', tf-idf = tf(કરે) x idf(કરે) = 1 x 1 = 1

    For 'વખાણ', tf-idf = tf(કરે) x idf(કરે) = 1 x 1.69314 = 1.69314

    For 'વધારે', tf-idf = tf(કરે) x idf(કરે) = 0 x 1.69314 = 0
   ```

   So for document1, the final tf-idf vector is `[1.69314  1  1  1.69314  0]`

   b. Now normalization is done (l2 Euclidean):

   ```
   dividor = sqrt(sqr(1.69314)+sqr(1)+sqr(1)+sqr(1.69314)+sqr(0))
            = sqrt(2.8667230596 + 1 + 1 + 2.8667230596 + 0)
            = sqrt(7.7334461192)
            = 2.7809074272977876...
   ```

   Dividing each element of the tf-idf array with dividor, we get:

   `[0.6088445  0.3595948  0.3595948548  0.6088445  0]`

   **Note:** This is the tfidf of firt document you posted in question.

   c. Now do the same steps a and b for document 2, we get:

   `[ 0.          0.453294  0.453294  0.          0.767494]`

**Update: About `sublinear_tf = True OR False`**

Your original term frequency vector is `[[1 1 1 1 0], [0 1 1 0 1]]` and you are correct in your understanding that using sublinear_tf = True will change the term frequency vector.

```
new_tf = 1 + log(tf)
```

Now the above line will only work on non zero elements in the term-frequecny. Because for 0, log(0) is undefined.

And all your non-zero entries are 1. `log(1)` is 0 and 1 + log(1) = 1 + 0 = 1`.

You see that the values will remain unchanged for elements with value 1. So your `new_tf = [[1 1 1 1 0], [0 1 1 0 1]] = tf(original)`.

Your term frequency is changing due to the `sublinear_tf` but it still remains the same.

And hence all below calculations will be same and output is same if you use `sublinear_tf=True` OR `sublinear_tf=False`.

Now if you change your documents for which the term-frequecy vector contains **elements other than 1 and 0**, you will get differences using the `sublinear_tf`.

Hope your doubts are cleared now.

Comment: Thank you. But one confusion. I have set `sublinear_tf = True`. It means that `tf` shall be calculated as `1 + log(tf)`. Is this true?

Comment: Please post the whole code you are using to find tfidf.

Comment: Also are you using `smooth_idf=False`?

Comment: Yes. `smooth_idf=False`. So, that is understood. I just have confusion about `sublinear_tf`. The value is not being changed in both `True` and `False` in this parameter. I have added line of code in my question.

Comment: Oh. Stupid me. This was really obvious. My bad. Thanks Vivek. It cleared my doubts.