# tfidf.transform() function not returning correct values

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to fit tfidf vectorizer on a certain text corpus and then use the same vectorizer to find the sum of tfidf values of the new text.However, the sum values are not as expected. Below is the example:

```
text = ["I am new to python and R , how can anyone help me","why is no one able to crack the python code without help"]
tf= TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',ngram_range =(1,1))
tf.fit_transform(text)
zip(tf.get_feature_names(),tf.idf_)

[(u'able', 1.4054651081081644),
 (u'code', 1.4054651081081644),
 (u'crack', 1.4054651081081644),
 (u'help', 1.0),
 (u'new', 1.4054651081081644),
 (u'python', 1.0)]
```

Now when i try the same `tf` with new text:

```
new_text = "i am not able to code"
np.sum(tf.transform([new_text]))
1.4142135623730951
```

I am expecting the output to be around 2.80.any suggestion on what might be going wrong here would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the 'l2 normalization' (default in TfidfVectorizer).
As you expect, the first result of the `transform()` is:

```
array([[ 1.40546511,  1.40546511,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ]])
```

But now the normalization is done. In this, the above vector is divided by the divider:

```
dividor = sqrt(sqr(1.40546511)+sqr(1.40546511)+sqr(0)+sqr(0)+sqr(0)+sqr(0))
        = sqrt(1.975332175+1.975332175+0+0+0+0)
        = 1.98762782
```

So the resulting final array is:

```
array([[ 0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ]])
```

And then you apply sum, its result is = `1.4142135623730951`.

Hope it is clear now. You can refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440621/how-term-frequency-is-calculated-in-tfidfvectorizer/42451555#42451555) for complete working of TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: To be clear, if you _don't_ want this L2-norm, you can use `norm=None` in the `TfidfVectorizer` constructor. See [here](https://repl.it/GkQ6/0).

Comment: Thanks for the lucid explanation. One follow up question though - why is that the tfidfs is normalized when we use it on the new text and not when we initially fit it to the original text?

Comment: @Apoorv  The original data is used to find the idf of the term from whole corpus. It doesnt compute tf-idf, which is based on single document. The tf-idf is normalized, not idf. If you use transform on the original documents, you will get normalized results. Dont be confused between tf and idf. You see idf=tf-idf in your case, because tf =1 for each term. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting

Comment: @Vivek Kumar Got it. Thank you for the quick help and reference. :)