# Is this correct tfidf?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to get tfidf from a document. But I dont think it is giving me correct values or I may be doing some thing wrong. Please suggest. Code and output below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
books = ["Hello there this is first book to be read by wordcount script.", "This is second book to be read by wordcount script. It has some additionl information.", "just third book."]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
response = vectorizer.fit_transform(books)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for col in response.nonzero()[1]:
   print feature_names[col], '-', response[0, col]
```

Update 1: (As suggested by juanpa.arrivillaga)

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False)
```

Output:

```
script - 0.269290317245
wordcount - 0.269290317245
by - 0.269290317245
read - 0.269290317245
be - 0.269290317245
to - 0.269290317245
book - 0.209127954024
first - 0.354084405732
is - 0.269290317245
this - 0.269290317245
there - 0.354084405732
hello - 0.354084405732
information - 0.0
...
```

Output after update 1:

```
script - 0.256536760895
wordcount - 0.256536760895
by - 0.256536760895
read - 0.256536760895
be - 0.256536760895
to - 0.256536760895
book - 0.182528018244
first - 0.383055542114
is - 0.256536760895
this - 0.256536760895
there - 0.383055542114
hello - 0.383055542114
information - 0.0
...
```

As per my understanding tfidf is = tf * idf. And the way I manually calculate it as example:

document 1: "Hello there this is first book to be read by wordcount script."
document 2: "This is second book to be read by wordcount script. It has some additionl information."
document 3: "just third book."

Tfidf for Hello:

```
tf= 1/12(total terms in document 1)= 0.08333333333
idf= log(3(total documents)/1(no. of document with term in it))= 0.47712125472
0.08333333333*0.47712125472= 0.03976008865
```

which is different from below (hello - 0.354084405732).

Manual calculation after update 1:

```
tf = 1
idf= log(nd/df) +1 = log (3/1) +1= 0.47712125472 + 1= 1.47712 
tfidf = tf*idf = 1* 1.47712= 1.47712
```

(not same as code output "hello - 0.383055542114" after idf smoothing)

Any help to understand whats going on is highly appreciated..

Comment: You can see exactly what is used [`here in the docs`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting). Note, you aren't doing IDF smoothing, which the `TfidfVectorizer` does by default.

Comment: Also, the docs seem to imply that term frequency is a raw term-frequency, not normalized by document length

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, can you turn your comment into an answer - this might help people searching/asking the same thing...

Comment: @MaxU I don't have the time right now, maybe later today...

Comment: You can look at my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451555/3374996) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092569/3374996) to know how the sklearn tfidfVectorizer works

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for suggestions. I have updated code but still not able to get same values from code and manual calculations..

Comment: @Manvi you aren't doing the manual calculation correctly, and certainly haven't seemed to grok how the default parameters affect smoothing and normalization...

Comment: @MaxU put up a basic example that doesn't do smoothing or normalization, just as a sanity check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an output without smoothing or normalization:

```
In [2]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
   ...: books = ["Hello there this is first book to be read by wordcount script.", "This is second book to be read by wordcount sc
   ...: ript. It has some additionl information.", "just third book."]
   ...: vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False, norm=None)
   ...: response = vectorizer.fit_transform(books)
   ...: feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
   ...: for col in response.nonzero()[1]:
   ...:    print(feature_names[col], '-', response[0, col])
   ...:
hello - 2.09861228867
there - 2.09861228867
this - 1.40546510811
is - 1.40546510811
first - 2.09861228867
book - 1.0
to - 1.40546510811
be - 1.40546510811
read - 1.40546510811
by - 1.40546510811
wordcount - 1.40546510811
script - 1.40546510811
this - 1.40546510811
is - 1.40546510811
book - 1.0
to - 1.40546510811
be - 1.40546510811
read - 1.40546510811
by - 1.40546510811
wordcount - 1.40546510811
script - 1.40546510811
second - 0.0
it - 0.0
has - 0.0
some - 0.0
additionl - 0.0
information - 0.0
book - 1.0
just - 0.0
third - 0.0
```

So consider the result for `"hello"`:

```
hello - 2.09861228867
```

Now, manually:

```
In [3]: import math

In [4]: tf = 1

In [5]: idf = math.log(3/1) + 1

In [6]: tf*idf
Out[6]: 2.09861228866811
```

The problem with your manual calculation is that you are using `log` base *10*, but you need to use the natural logarithm.

If you still feel the burning desire to go through the smoothing and normalization steps, this should set you up to do it correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I get it now..can you please also suggest how to remove warning that I am getting with same code as"VisibleDeprecationWarning: `rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim` attribute or function instead."

Comment: @Manvi I have no idea where that warning is coming from. It seems like you should ask another question, but also, it seems pretty self explanatory - don't use the `rank` argument to whatever function is giving you that warning, use `ndim` or a function instead...

Comment: @Manvi it seems like that is coming from the underlying `sklearn` implementation, which uses a deprecated `scipy` function. Probably this has been fixed - I don't get the warning. Try updating `sklearn`

Comment: @Manvi I was on version 18, version 19 was releasde a couple of days ago!

Comment: One more thing, code is printing tfidf=0.0 for few..is this correct ?also.. why is it printing 0 while using response.nonzero()[1].

Comment: @Manvi this really should be another question - but basically, you are just iterating over the *column indices* of values in your 2-dimensional sparse matrix that have `non_zero` value. But *every* value in there is *nonzero somewhere*. Just print your matrix, it should be obvious