# Sklearn Tfidf Vectorizer norm=None norm-l2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

Hi I'm trying to understand how scikit-learn works out the TFIDF score in the matrix: document 1, feature 6, "wine":

```
test_doc = ['The wine was lovely', 'The red was delightful',
            'Terrible choice of wine', 'We had a bottle of red']

# Create vectorizer
vec = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
# Feature vector
tfidf = vec.fit_transform(test_doc)

feature_names = vec.get_feature_names()
feature_matrix = tfidf.todense()

['bottle', 'choice', 'delightful', 'lovely', 'red', 'terrible', 'wine']
[[ 0.         0.         0.         0.78528828 0.        0.         0.6191303 ]
 [ 0.         0.         0.78528828 0.         0.6191303 0.         0.        ]
 [ 0.         0.61761437 0.         0.         0.        0.61761437 0.48693426]
 [ 0.78528828 0.         0.         0.         0.6191303 0.         0.        ]]
```

I was using the answer to a very similar question to calculate it for myself:
[How areTF-IDF calculated by the scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966019/how-aretf-idf-calculated-by-the-scikit-learn-tfidfvectorizer) However in their TFIDFVectorizer, norm=None.

As I'm using the default setting of norm=l2, how does this differ to norm=None and how can I calculate it for myself?

Comment: Maybe other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440621/how-term-frequency-is-calculated-in-tfidfvectorizer/42451555#42451555) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43091235/tfidf-transform-function-not-returning-correct-values/43092569#43092569) help you

Comment: @VivekKumar this is really helpful, thank you!

Comment: @VivekKumar, I'm trying to reproduce the answer to your calculation: log(2/1)+1 but I'm getting 1.301 not 0.693... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the base in your calculations. It should be ln(2/1) (with base 2). I think you are using log(2/1) with base 10. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90594/the-difference-between-log-and-ln)

Answer (score 0):

After some computations:

The TFIDF vectrors of the documents (tfidf.todense()) is computed from the formula:

- `TFIDF = tf(t,d) * idf(t,D)`
- `tf(t,d)` = how many times word-t appear  into the document d (don't divide
  with the total words of the document)
- `idf(t,D) = ln ( (1 + D) / (1 + df))`

  - D = number of the documents
  - df = We are looking into all documents, if word-t exist in a`document_i`
    and we add +1 to df (we dont care if word-t exist many times in a
    documents)

Parameter norm

- norm = None : Compute TFIDF vectors with the above formula
- norm = 'l2' : Compute TFIDF vectors with the above formula and for each -TFIDF vector,  we compute its length. So the new TFIDF vectors is computed as
- TFIDF_vector_i = TFIDF_vector_i / (length_TFIDF_vector_i)
- length_TFIDF_vector_i = Sqrt(Sum(tfidt[i]^2)) [compute vector's length image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMyge.png)