# tf-idf calculation using the scikit-learn feature extraction module

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Please read the post completely before flagging. I have looked everywhere on  the internet to try to figure this out.

I am simply trying to work through [this machine learning tutorial](http://www.example.chttp://blog.christianperone.com/2011/10/machine-learning-text-feature-extraction-tf-idf-part-ii/) and am having trouble replicating the results. Furthermore I can't mathematically replicate the results I am producing. Everything is clear until I try to generate the tfidf as seen in the comments in the code below.

To be specific, am I correctly generating the tfidf below?
If so, how can I replicate mathematically as it's my understanding it should simply be tf * idf where both are simple calculations as seen in the comments below.

Thanks in advance!

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
train_set = ("The sky is blue.", "The sun is bright.")
test_set = ("The sun in the sky is bright.", 
    "We can see the shining sun, the bright sun.")

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
document_term_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_set)
print vectorizer.vocabulary_
# Vocabulary: {u'blue': 0, u'sun': 3, u'bright': 1, u'sky': 2}
freq_term_matrix = vectorizer.transform(test_set)
print freq_term_matrix.todense()
# [[0 1 1 1]
# [0 1 0 2]]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(freq_term_matrix)
# The arguments as the are passed int0 TfidfTransformer: 
# TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False, use_idf=True)

print "IDF:", tfidf.idf_
# This is where the confusion begins. What are these numbers?
# IDF: [ 2.09861229  1.          1.40546511  1.        ]


tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(freq_term_matrix)
print tf_idf_matrix.todense()
# It's my understanding that these are simply tf * idf where 
# tf = (number of times a word appears in a doc) / (number of words in document)
# idf = log((number of documents) / (number of docs the word appears in))
# [[ 0.          0.50154891  0.70490949  0.50154891]
# [ 0.          0.4472136   0.          0.89442719]]
```

Comment: You can go through [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451555/3374996) which describes this in detail

Comment: @VivekKumar Hi there! Thanks for your response. I am still seeing some issues. When I set smooth_idf to false I return an inf value in my IDF.